# c# Type Inference - Error - There is no implicit reference conversion from

Tags: c#, type-inference

I have a method that loops through a list of guids and saves them to a database via DbContext. B is a DbSet collection of WebObjects (example: `DbSet<MlaPerson> MlaPersons`)

```
protected void AddRelatedWebObject<A, B>(A mlaObject, B inputObject, List<Guid> guids) 
    where A : WebObject 
    where B : DbSet<WebObject>
{
    foreach (Guid guid in guids)
    {
        mlaObject.RelatedWebObjects.Add(inputObject.Find(guid));
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**usage**:

```
foreach (ArticleRelationships item in articleRelationships)
{
    MlaArticle article = new MlaArticle();
    article = _db.MlaArticles.Include(m => m.WebSite).Where(m => m.Id == item.ArticleId).First();
    AddRelatedWebObject<MlaArticle, DbSet<MlaPerson>>(article, _db.MlaPersons, item.PersonIds);
}
```

**_db.MlaPersons are defined as**:

```
public class ECM2Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MlaPerson> MlaPersons { get; set; }
}
```

**and MlaPerson is defined as**:

```
public class MlaPerson : WebObject, IValidatableObject
{
    ...
}
```

I thought that by inferring that B was `DbSet<WebObject>` would work because MlaPerson's base class is WebObject, but I'm wrong. I'm getting the error:

`The type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<ExternalContentManager.Models.MlaPerson>' cannot be used as a type parameter 'B' in the generic type or method 'AddRelatedWebObjects'. There is not implicit reference conversion from 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<ExternalContentManager.Models.MlaPerson>' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<ExternalContentManager.Models.WebObject>'`

I would really appreciate any and all help offered. Thanks for your help.
B

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are making a common generics error- assuming that collections are covariant.  That is, a an instance of `List<Car>` does not inherit from `List<Vehicle>` even though car inherits from vehicle.  Likewise, `DbSet<MlaPerson>` does not inherit from `DbSet<WebObject>` even though MlaPerson inherits from WebObject.

What you need to do is something like this (I haven't tested this code):

```
protected void AddRelatedWebObject<A, B, O>(A mlaObject, B inputObject, List<Guid> guids) 
    where A : WebObject 
    where B : DbSet<O>
    where O : WebObject
{
    foreach (Guid guid in guids)
    {
        mlaObject.RelatedWebObjects.Add(inputObject.Find(guid));
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

and use it thus:

```
foreach (ArticleRelationships item in articleRelationships)
{
    MlaArticle article = new MlaArticle();
    article = _db.MlaArticles.Include(m => m.WebSite).Where(m => m.Id == item.ArticleId).First();
    AddRelatedWebObject<MlaArticle, DbSet<MlaPerson>, MlaPerson>(article, _db.MlaPersons, item.PersonIds);
}
```

If you do it this way, you may be able to forgo the type specification (`<MlaArticle, DbSet<MlaPerson>, MlaPerson>`) because it should infer it.

Answer (score 7):

A `DbSet<MlaPerson>` isn't a `DbSet<WebObject>` just because `MlaPerson` derives from `WebObject`. Search for "generic variance" on Stack Overflow to find lots of reasons why.

You might want to change your method parameters and constraints like this:

```
protected void AddRelatedWebObject<A, B>(A mlaObject, DbSet<B> inputObject,
                                         List<Guid> guids) 
    where A : WebObject 
    where B : WebObject
```

And then call it like this:

```
AddRelatedWebObject<MlaArticle, MlaPerson>(article, _db.MlaPersons,
                                           item.PersonIds);
```

That may work - it may even work with type inference to allow this:

```
AddRelatedWebObject(article, _db.MlaPersons, item.PersonIds);
```

I would *also* suggest that you rename your type parameters to something like `TSource` and `TTarget` to be clearer, and to follow conventions.

Comment: This looks right also, I just tried the other answer first. I +1'd you though. Thanks for your answer/explanation. It was thorough and easy to understand.

Comment: @bflemi3: The benefit of my answer over the accepted one (IMO) is that it involves fewer type parameters, and is therefore simpler. I can't see that the `B` type parameter is actually doing anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

**--EDIT - THIS ANSWER IS WRONG. SEE THE COMMENTS FOR MORE INFO--**

Upcasting does not work with containers(unless you are upcasting the data structure, but that's not the case here). Imagine the following code(written with arrays for simplicity, but the same principles apply for all generic containers):

```
class A{}
class B:A{}

/*Inside a method*/
B[] arrayB=new B[10];
A[] arrayA=arrayB;//This line will produce a compile error
arrayA[0]=new A();
```

Now `arrayB[0]` contains an object of type A, even though it `A` is not a derived class of `B`. That's why upcasting does not work for containers.

Comment: **This answer is wrong; the given code succeeds at compile time**. C# supports non-typesafe element-type variance on arrays if both element types are reference types. It is my candidate for "worst feature of C#". That line does *not* produce a compile error, and if you run your code you'll find that it fails at runtime.

Comment: Dammit... that's what I get for answering based on knowledge without checking the code... Anyways, it doesn't work for generic containers(I did checked **that**), but That would be due to technicality reasons, and not due to proper language design.  
Someone downvote my answer please.

Comment: Yeah, nothing quite like being slapped down by one of the guys responsible for making C# work :P

Comment: Any sensible person would reasonably expect this to produce a compilation error in a statically-typed language; it is deeply regrettable that it does not.  Note that C# 4 **does** support  covariance on *generic interfaces and delegates constructed with reference type arguments* when the compiler can prove that the conversion is typesafe.

Comment: @Eric Lippert  You just made my day.  Does that mean it will implicitly convert ObservableCollection<subclass> to ObservableCollection<superclass>?

Comment: @BahriGungor: Regrettably, no. `ObservableCollection<T>` is not a *generic interface or delegate*. By contrast `IEnumerable<T>` is a generic interface, and the compiler can prove that it is typesafe to use it covariantly. See the FAQ for details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx. If you are interested in the design of the feature, see my series of articles on how we designed it. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/default.aspx